# How to build another Widget inside a button's onTap function

Tags: flutter, widget, parameter-passing

EDIT (2nd):
I made a change the state from Stateful widgets to Stateless widget, and it turns out, I can solve the problem.

EDIT:
So I made a mistake, I shouldn't be making a widget inside onTap function,  Instead, I should've instantiate CardMatcher somewhere and then access CardMatcher, send the button's keyword, and let CardMatcher check the keyword for me when the button is clicked.

Any Idea how to do that? Can someone make a simple code for me?

In other words, I want to make a widget that can check if there are two buttons that have been clicked. That widget, should be in another file so it may be reused.
ーーーー

So I made a custom button that will pass a keyword to another widget (CardMatcher) that will check the keyword. If two buttons have the same keywords, then the widget (CardMatcher) will do something about it.

The button will pass the keyword when it is clicked. Sadly, nothing happens. There's no error detected, but the app didn't build the CardMatcher as well. Here's the code for the button:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttermatchcard/cardMatcher.dart';
import 'package:fluttermatchcard/cardMatcher.dart';
import 'package:fluttermatchcard/testerState.dart';

class CardButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget child;
  //final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  final double widthBut;
  final double heightBut;
  final Color colorInitial;
  final Color colorClicked ;
  final Color textColorInitial ;
  final Color textColorClicked ;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final Text text;
  final String keyword;

  CardButton({
    //@required this.onPressed,
    this.child,
    @required this.keyword,
    this.heightBut =40,
    this.widthBut = 75,
    this.colorClicked = Colors.white,
    this.colorInitial=Colors.amber,
    this.textColorClicked = Colors.amber,
    this.textColorInitial = Colors.white,
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,
    this.text = const Text(
                           "Card",
                              style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),

  });

  @override
  _CardButtonState createState() => _CardButtonState(
      keyword,
      widthBut,
      heightBut,
      colorClicked,
      colorInitial,
      textColorClicked,
      textColorInitial,
      alignment,
      text,
  );
}

class _CardButtonState extends State<CardButton> {

  String _keyword;
  double _widthBut ;
  double _heightBut;
  Color _colorInitial;
  Color _colorClicked ;
  Color _textColorInitial;
  Color _textColorClicked ;
  Alignment _alignment ;
  Text _text;

  _CardButtonState(
      this._keyword,
      this._widthBut,
      this._heightBut,
      this._colorClicked,
      this._colorInitial,
      this._textColorClicked,
      this._textColorInitial,
      this._alignment,
      this._text,
      );

  Color _colorNow;
  Color _textColorNow;

  bool isClicked = false;

  void initState() {
    _colorNow=_colorInitial;
    _text = Text(_text.data, style: TextStyle(color: _textColorInitial, fontSize: _text.style.fontSize),);
    super.initState();
  }

  void ChangeButton(){

    setState(() {
      isClicked= !isClicked;
      if(isClicked){
        _colorNow=_colorClicked;
        _text = Text(_text.data, style: TextStyle(color: _textColorClicked, fontSize: _text.style.fontSize),);
      }
      else{
        _colorNow=_colorInitial;
        _text = Text(_text.data, style: TextStyle(color: _textColorInitial, fontSize: _text.style.fontSize),);
      }
    });

    //super.initState();//no idea

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: _widthBut,
      height: _heightBut,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){ChangeButton();
        CardMatcher(_keyword);
        print("onTap");},
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          alignment: _alignment,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: _colorNow,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(0,2),
                    spreadRadius: 2
                )
              ],
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.amberAccent
              )
          ),
          child: _text,
        ),
      ),
    );
    //widget.onPressed();
  }
}
```

for the CardMatcher:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardMatcher extends StatefulWidget {
  final String keyword_now;
  CardMatcher(this.keyword_now);

  @override
  _CardMatcherState createState() {
    print("cardMatch");

    _CardMatcherState(keyword_now);
  }
}

class _CardMatcherState extends State<CardMatcher> {
  String _keyword_1;
  String _keyword_2;
  String _keyword_now;

  _CardMatcherState(
      this._keyword_now,
      );

  void _collectKeywords(){
    print("EnterCollect");

    setState(() {
      if(_keyword_1==null)
        {
          print("key1");
          _keyword_1=_keyword_now;
        }
      else{
        _keyword_2=_keyword_now;
        _matchKeyword(_keyword_1,_keyword_2);
      }
    });
  }

  void _matchKeyword(_keyWord_one, _keyWord_two){
    if(_keyWord_one==_keyWord_two){
      //Lock the But
      print("MATCH!!!!");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("BUILD");
    _collectKeywords();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Save me, please

Comment: The code inside your InkWell doesn't make sense. You are trying to put a Widget inside a method. It's not proper Dart/Flutter code. You should be displaying the Widget and then make changes based on variables declared in the state of your class. Just by your code, it's not easy to understand what you actually want to achieve. A simpler example would give you better responses.

Comment: my bad. I tried to instantiate my CardMatcher inside my my Screen Widget, but nothing also happened. It seems like everytime I want to make a widget that has no return value, flutter won't make that kind of widget for me. So, maybe the proper questions would be: How and where do you make a widget that has no return value? Then, how can you change the variables of that widget from another widget?

Comment: Let's try to simplify this. You want to change which widget you are showing based on a variable? Or do you want to change the variables inside a widget based on variables coming from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I have found a solution for this problem (at least temporary solution). Thank you guys, for helping!! You guys are awesoe. Sorry for not being precise in my words

Answer (score 0):

You try to create the `CardMatcher` widget in your `onTap` function!
What you need to do:
 1. `onTap` must **just** call `ChangeButton` (but don't create `CardMatcher` here)
 2. `ChangeButton` must call `setState()` **AND** change the `_keyword` field
 3. Use a `CardMatcher` instance in your build tree with `_keyword` as constructor parameter

When calling `setState`, you indicate to flutter to rebuild (i.e. call `build()`) the widget. If you change a state (i.e. `_keyword`), then the `build` method will use the new state's value to build the widget accordling

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sorry I don't get it... I tried your suggestions, but I think I missed something

Comment: I think the right questions would be: 
1.How do you instantiate a stateful widget (CardMacther) inside a stateles widget (for example,a screen called Home)? CardMacther is not a U.I., how and where do you write it down?

2. How can a button access another widget's variable. If I'm not getting you wrong, the button will change "keyword" that is declared in CardMatcher, and then set a new state for CardMatcher, right? How do have the access to change its  variable?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems to be missing in your code is for you to use the `widget.` prefix to access the `Stateful` widgets constructor variables, like this:

```
class CardMatcher extends StatefulWidget {
  final String keyword_now;
  CardMatcher(this.keyword_now);

  @override
  _CardMatcherState createState() {
    print("cardMatch");

    _CardMatcherState(keyword_now);
  }
}

class _CardMatcherState extends State<CardMatcher> {
  String _keyword_1;
  String _keyword_2;


  void _collectKeywords(){
    print("EnterCollect");

    setState(() {
      if(_keyword_1 == null)
        {
          print("key1");
          _keyword_1 = widget.keyword_now;
        }
      else{
        _keyword_2 = widget.keyword_now;
        _matchKeyword(_keyword_1,_keyword_2);
      }
    });
  }

  void _matchKeyword(_keyWord_one, _keyWord_two){
    if(_keyWord_one==_keyWord_two){
      //Lock the But
      print("MATCH!!!!");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("BUILD");
    _collectKeywords();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm... Thanks for replying, but I think that doesn't solve my problem. The thing is, CardMatcher is supposed to be built when I clicked (onTap) the button, but somehow CardMatcher doesn't show up (I tried to print "cardMatch" in the build, sadly nothing appeared).